# How can I query an AppHost for a specific route?

Tags: servicestack

Basically I have following architecture:

- Website-project (1)
- Domain-project (2)
- Api-project (3)

Dependencies:

- 1 uses 2 and 3
- 3 uses 2
- 2 uses nothing

In my Api-project I define a concrete implementation of `ServiceStack.Webhost.Endpoints.AppHostBase`, eg `ApiAppHost`:

```
public sealed class ApiAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    private ApiAppHost()
        : base("Description", typeof (ApiAppHost).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        this.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api"
        });

        this.Routes.Add<Foo>("/foo", "POST");
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var instance = new ApiAppHost();
        instance.Init();
    }
}
```

This is pretty straight-forward.

Now I want to query my `this.Routes` (in combination with `EndpointHostConfig.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath`) from my Website-project to get *the* specific path for `Foo`.

How can I do that without creating an interceptor on my own? Does ServiceStack.Net provide anything which fits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I am doing something like this

```
public static class AppHostBaseExtensions
{
    public static string GetUrl<TRequest>(this AppHostBase appHostBase)
    {
        var requestType = typeof (TRequest);

        return appHostBase.GetUrl(requestType);
    }

    public static string GetUrl(this AppHostBase appHostBase, Type requestType)
    {
        var endpointHostConfig = appHostBase.Config;
        var serviceStackHandlerFactoryPath = endpointHostConfig.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath;

        var serviceRoutes = appHostBase.Routes as ServiceRoutes;
        if (serviceRoutes == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Property Routes of AppHostBase is not of type ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRoutes");
        }
        var restPaths = serviceRoutes.RestPaths;
        var restPath = restPaths.FirstOrDefault(arg => arg.RequestType == requestType);
        if (restPath == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var path = restPath.Path;
        var virtualPath = "~/" + string.Concat(serviceStackHandlerFactoryPath, path); // bad, i know, but combining with 2 virtual paths ...
        var absolutePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath);

        return absolutePath;
    }
}
```

I know that it is wrong because of many issues (path-combining, not taking rest-paths into account, not taking rest-paths with placeholders into account), but it works as a start ...

Edit:
And this only works, if you register the route within `Configure(Container)` of your `AppHostBase`-implementation. It wont't work with the `RestServiceAttribute`-attribute ...